# AWS S3 and AWS ELB instead of AWS Elastic beanstalk for SPA Angular 6 application

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-elb

I am creating an Angular 6 frontend application. My backend api are created in DotNet. Assume the application is similar to https://www.amazon.com/.

My query is related to frontend portion deployment related only, on AWS. Large number of users with variable count pattern are expected on my portal. I thought of using AWS elastic beanstalk as PAAS web server.

Can AWS S3/ ELB be used instead of PAAS beanstalk without any limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by combining an Elastic Load Balancer with S3. I think you may be confused as to the purpose of the ELB, which is to distribute requests to multiple servers e.g. NodeJS servers, but cannot be used with S3 which is already highly available.

There are numerous options when serving an Angular app:

- You could serve the files using a nodejs app, but unless you are doing server-side rendering (using Angular Universal), then I don't see the point because you are just serving static files (files that don't get stitched together by a server such as when you use PHP). It is more complicated to deploy and maintain a server, even using Elastic Beanstalk, and it is probably difficult to get the same performance as you could do with other setups (see below).
- What I suspect most people would do is to configure an S3 bucket to host and serve the static files of your Angular app (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html). You basically configure your domain name to resolve to the S3 bucket's url. This is extremely cheap, as you are not paying for a server which is running constantly, but rather only have to pay the small storage cost and plus a data transfer fee which would be directly proportional to your traffic.
- You can further improve on the S3 setup by creating a CloudFront distribution that uses your S3 bucket as it's origin (the location that it get files from). When you configure your domain name to resolve to your CloudFront distribution, then instead of a user's request getting the files from the S3 bucket (which could be in a region on the other side of the world and so slower), the request will be directed to the closest "edge location" which will be much closer to your user, and check if files are cached there first. It is basically a global content delivery network for your files. This is a bit more expensive than S3 on it's own. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/.